# Problems with strftime encoding under Windows

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, strftime

I've got a problem using [strftime('%B')](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) under Windows. The problem is that under Windows this function returns a non-UTF-8 encoded string (as Windows does not support UTF-8 locales).

I have googled a lot about this subject and found a lot of advice to just use [utf8_encode(strftime('%B'))](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php), but that does not help. I get a very strange string after `utf8_encode`.

There is another solution: to use [mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php), for example:

```
$month = strftime('%B');
$month = mb_convert_encoding($month, 'UTF-8', 'CP1251'); // For Russian locale
```

It works, but that is only good when you are developing for an exact locale. But I need a universal solution. You may suggest:

```
$month = strftime('%B');
$month = mb_convert_encoding($month, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($month));
```

But this does not work, because even if `$month` is non-utf8, `mb_detect_encoding($month)` returns 'UTF-8'.

Is there a solution? I need a universal solution, because I'm going to make a [pull request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control#Pull_requests) to my favourite [Laravel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel) framework (it has Form::selectMonth() function that generates an HTML `select` input, prefilled with months, which works perfectly for Linux systems, but fails under localized Windows systems).

Comment: Yes i have faced with this problem once and still didn't find a solution. I end up avoiding `mb_detect_encoding` and just give in the iso of the language i wish to get the formatted time, along with a [**setlocale**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) call.

Comment: *[strftime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)* now says *"This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 8.1.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged."*.

Comment: *[utf8_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)* now says *"This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 8.2.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged."*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, '');

echo(iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8', strftime('%B')));
```